# F# [<Literal>] causes Invalid Program

Tags: f#, guid, literals

I'm trying to match the Empty Guid using a Literal, and I can't figure out what's going on here:

```
let [<Literal>] EmptyGuid = System.Guid ()

let someFunction () = System.Guid.NewGuid () |> Some

match someFunction () with
| None           -> printfn "None"
| Some EmptyGuid -> printfn "Some EmptyGuid" 
  // ^ Comment this line out and it works! 
| Some guid      -> guid.ToString "D" |> printfn "Some Guid: %s"
```

When I try to run the program above, I get two different Exceptions somewhat randomly:

> AccessViolationException was unhandled:
>   Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

Or:

> InvalidProgramException was unhandled:
>   Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program.

This can't be my fault, can it? Either I'm incredibly stupid or there is something really weird going on...

**EDIT:**

I just noticed when which exception appears:

- AccessViolationException when using .NET 4.5
- InvalidProgramException when using .NET 4

Comment: The first line on its own is enough to crash my fsi.  I think it also board the spec.  You need to use when guards to do what you aretying to do

Comment: That's what I ended up doing. I don't understand why this is happening, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the spec

> ·         The right-hand side expression must be a literal constant
>   expression that is made up of either:
>
> ·         A simple constant expression, with the exception of (),
>   native integer literals, unsigned native integer literals, byte array
>   literals, BigInteger literals, and user-defined numeric literals.
>
> —OR—
>
> ·         A reference to another literal.

So I would think that your RHS does not follow the spec.

Neverthelss, I think you should be getting a more helpful error message.  This should be reported as a bug to fsbugs@microsoft.com

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. I will send an eMail, it really should not compile.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why that it lets you compile that at all.  `System.Guid` is not an F# literal (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd233193%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)).  As John noted, you will need to do this with something other than a literal.  Also, you might better off using `System.Guid.Empty` rather than `System.Guid()` if you want the default `Guid`.

Comment: I used Guid () because the compiler complained that Guid.Empty is not a valid literal expression ;)

Comment: Oh and thanks for the link, I always thought of literals as the equivalent of C# const. I assumed every struct could be a literal.